# QCamera get resolution and raw frame

Tags: c++, qt, qcamera

I would like to get the resolution of the selected camera and also get the raw frame in the videocapture but I have not found clearly at all how to do it. Could you help me!? Thanks in advance.

```
    // Open camera for reading
    cameraQt = new QCamera(cameras.at(cameraIdSelected));
    if(!cameraQt->isAvailable())
          ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Impossible to open camera...."));

    cameraQt->setViewfinder(ui->centralWidget);
```

like : `cameraQt->getResolution` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Studying this would help https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html

Comment: Oh thanks! I was reading it previously, but I have not found how to get the "default" resolution of the "default" camera. But I will take a loot more deeply.

Answer (score 2):

I think you 1) Should load the cam 2) get imageCapture (raw) from the loaded cam. There is no direct simple type of a resolution, because camera will have a `list` of supported resolutions, you can set your device to one of those.

Try this to get the list of resolutions for a device:

```
QList<QByteArray> cameraDevices = QCamera::availableDevices();
QByteArray cameraDevice = cameraDevices[0];
QCamera *camera = new QCamera(cameraDevice);
camera->load();
qDebug() << "Camera status: " << camera->status();
QCameraImageCapture *imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
QList<QSize> resolutions = imageCapture->supportedResolutions();
QListIterator<QSize> it(resolutions);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << "Resoution: " << it.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I was missing the load() method. :)

Comment: Hello! Sorry for answering still now. It did not work, but I think it is due to other things. I had having this error ( I copied the error from other post), but like this:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/78433/qt-multimeia-gstreamer-critical-error/2

But I do not know if it was a conflict with the opencv camera or some problem in my OS. Because I have all gstreamer plugins installed...Tomorrow I will continue with that project.

Thanks so much anyway. :)